# How to present a View controller from a button which is within a tablecell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a view controller which has a tableview in it. I have a class ProductCell.swift and controller ProductVC.swift . What i need is, when someone taps on the username button in tableCell , then it should present the profile view controller. 
[here is the error image link . the error in description is : unexpectedily found nil while unwrapping an optional](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkkC3.png)
i have tried:

```
self.window?.rootViewController!.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

i have also tried calling delegates.

Both of the above solution give the same error code.

The error is shown on the tableview datasource and delegate = self and when i remove these from viewDidLoad() then it shows error on the self.tableview.reloadData()

I saw 3,4 questions on the same issue but none of the solutions worked for me. 
please let me know if the question is not clear. I will explain it again.

i am stuck in this from hours.

UPDATING CODES

FOR CatPlaceTableViewCell

```
import UIKit

protocol TableViewCellDelegate
{
   func buttonDidClicked()
}

class CatPlaceTableViewCell: UITableViewCell{
var delegate: TableViewCellDelegate?


@IBOutlet weak var sponsoredView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var catProfilePic: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var catProfileName: UIButton!

@IBAction func catProfileNameBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    self.delegate?.buttonDidClicked()


}
@IBOutlet weak var catPostTime: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var catPostImage: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var catPostTitle: UILabel!



override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()



}

func configureCell(post : PlacesDetails)
{

    catPostTitle.text = post.title
    catProfileName.setTitle(post.fullName, for: .normal)
    catPostTime.text = post.postTime

}
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}


}
```

FOR PlaceCategoryVC:

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SDWebImage

class PlaceCategoryVC: UIViewController , UITableViewDataSource , UITableViewDelegate , TableViewCellDelegate{




@IBOutlet weak var headerPanel: UIView!

@IBOutlet weak var searchLocation: UISearchBar!

@IBOutlet weak var applyFIlter: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var resetFilter: UIButton!

@IBAction func applyFilterBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
}

@IBAction func resetFilterBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
}

////////////////////////////

@IBOutlet weak var catPostTable: UITableView!


typealias DownloadComplete1 = () -> ()

var post : PlacesDetails!
var posts = [PlacesDetails]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    catPostTable.dataSource = self
    catPostTable.delegate = self

    downloadPostData {}


}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return posts.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell : CatPlaceTableViewCell = catPostTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "catPlaces", for: indexPath) as! CatPlaceTableViewCell
//       cell.delegate = self
    if(indexPath.row % 5 == 4)
    {
        cell.sponsoredView.isHidden = false
    }
    else
    {
        cell.sponsoredView.isHidden = true
    }

    cell.catProfilePic.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: posts[indexPath.row].profileImageURL), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "default_image.png"))
    cell.catPostImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: posts[indexPath.row].contentURL), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))
    let post1 = posts[indexPath.row]
    cell.configureCell(post: post1)

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("\(posts[indexPath.row].postid)")
    let indexpath1 = posts[indexPath.row].postid
    UserDefaults.standard.setValue(indexpath1, forKey: "postIdOfSinglePOst")
    let viewController:UIViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SinglePostSB") as UIViewController

    self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func downloadPostData(completed: @escaping DownloadComplete1) {
    var  i = 1
    repeat {
        Alamofire.request("https://www.EXAMPLE.COM?category=places&page=\(i)").responseJSON { response in
            let result = response.result
            print(result)
            if let dict = result.value as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject> {

                if let successcode = dict["STATUS_CODE"] as? Int {
                    if successcode == 1 {
                        if let postsArray = dict["posts"] as? [Dictionary<String,AnyObject>]
                        {
                            for obj in postsArray
                            {
                                let post = PlacesDetails(postDict: obj)
                                self.posts.append(post)
                                print(self.posts)

                            }
                            self.catPostTable.reloadData()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        i = i + 1
    }
        while(i<2)

    completed()
}

var delegate: TableViewCellDelegate?
func buttonDidClicked()
{
    let vc = ProductVC()

    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

}

Comment: can you show some more code

Comment: ok wait i am updating the code

Comment: Can you also print your error message here

Comment: its terminating with an uncaught exception. and prints only some error codes no description .

Comment: Are you sure the issue is in this controller and not in your ProductVC? Try replacing it with let vc = UIViewController(). If the issue persists then the issue is here, otherwise you probably messed up ProductVC.

Comment: Posting the error you are getting when the 'username' button is tapped would help a lot.  It looks like you have wired your TableView and actions correctly, assuming that you don't leave the `cell.delegate = self` line commented.  You should `init` your Product VC from storyboard/Nib file as well, while it doesn't feel like it at times with iOS, the 'view' and 'view controller' are separate.  OR create your segue in storyboard and call it using the identifier

Comment: You defined a Delegate Protocol for the button tap, but then you commented out the line that assigns the delegate. So, uncomment `cell.delegate = self` in `cellForRowAt` ... Then, delete the line `var delegate: TableViewCellDelegate?` from `PlaceCategoryVC` - it has no purpose there. At that point, your button tap *should* call `buttonDidClicked()`, but you're not passing any information about *which* button was tapped.

Comment: Also... are you trying to do different actions if the *cell* is tapped vs. if the *button in the cell* is tapped?

Comment: yes if the cell is tapped then its opening the post . and if the button is tapped then its opening the profile.

Comment: i have updated the image link. whatever solution i implement, i get stuck here only. see the image

Comment: Have you made sure that all the IBOutlets from CatPlaceTableViewCell are properly connected?

Comment: your `catPostTable` is a weak var, so it is being released(remove the weak keyword)...you still need to watch retainCounts when using ARC ;)

Comment: i removed it but then also same error

Comment: `catPostTable` is an `IBOutlet` ... it's supposed to be `weak`.

Comment: Take a step back for a moment... Ignoring your desire to act on row selection and "inside cell" button tap... Do you have working code that loads and displays your table of "posts"? If not, get that working first... If you *do* have that working, then step through in debug and find the exact line that is causing the error.

Comment: Just to add some clarity to @DonMag 's comment, -- "In general you should make your outlet strong, especially if you are connecting an outlet to a sub view or to a constraint that's not always going to be retained by the view hierarchy. The only time you really need to make an outlet weak is if you have a custom view that references something back up the view hierarchy and in general that's not recommended."  ([Implementing UI Designs](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/407/))

Comment: each of my viewcontroller works. presenting from one viewcontroller to other view controller also works for buttons that are in view controller .. only the tablecell buttons are not working and givibg the same error . its really frustrating :/ ..can u find any error in my code ?

Comment: Your picture is referencing a "resultTable" variable, but I do not see it anywhere in the code you provided

Comment: Ugh... while this problem is unrelated to declaring `IBOutlet catPostTable` as weak or strong, gotta luv Apple's flip-flopping and ambiguity. From Resource Programming Guide *"Outlets should generally be weak, except for those from File’s Owner to top-level objects in a nib file (or, in iOS, a storyboard scene) which should be strong. Outlets that you create should therefore typically be weak..."* https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH4-SW6

Comment: This question needs a lot of cleanup. The problem (based on the picture) is about trying to set the delegate and dataSource on a variable named "resultTable". Other than your picture, nothing about your question applies to the issue. Remove all of the code you have posted so far and post relevant code from the picture you posted of the error.

Comment: You need to read full question. If you are not able to understand then it doesnt mean others are not. Gaining a lot of reputation doesnt mean you downvote others without any reason. @rmaddy . As a beginner of stackoverflow, downvote does affect me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having more of a problem debugging/finding your issue then how to present a view controller.

As you claim the error is accessing a force-unwrapped object you need to find which this object is. In general try to avoid force unwrapping at all cost so make sure that the "!" symbol is not found in your code. That includes outlets for which I can't stress enough to always change them into

```
@IBOutlet private weak var <#name#>: <#type#>?
```

weather it should be weak or strong is for another discussion so do whatever as I doubt it will make a difference in your case.

So removing the force-unwrapping should fix your crash but I assume that will simply produce another issue because calling `object?.doSomething()` will do nothing when `object` is `nil`. So debugging is needed:

1. Learn about exception breakpoints. Have them always enabled. All you need to do is go to breakpoint navigation in Xcode, then on bottom press the "+" button and select "exception breakpoint". By doing and running your app you should now find the exact location where the error occurs as your app will stop on that specific line of code. Let us know what line caused the crash after doing so.
2. Use breakpoints in general. On every line you can place a breakpoint by pressing just left of the code you have written. Place a breakpoint in the method which is the action of the button (probably `catProfileNameBtnPressed`) and once the breakpoint is hit start navigating to next line (use buttons just below the text editor) and follow the pipeline to see which methods are called and if the pipeline is correct.
3. Use console to print objects when in runtime when on breakpoint. At any point when in breakpoint you may print results of code in the console (should be on bottom right part of Xcode where the logs are printed and outputs from `print`). All you need to do is write `"po" + code` to get any value. So for instance you can write "po delegate" when breakpoint in `CatPlaceTableViewCell` and you should see a value of `delegate`. If it is `nil` then your delegate was not set. You can print out complex messages so just get whatever you need like `po String(data: try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dictionary, options: .prettyPrinted), encoding: 4)` is completely valid.

Now use these 3 tools to find where exactly your issue lies. Follow the execution pipeline and come up with a concrete question like "Why is my button action method not being called" or "Why is my delegate nil although it has been set" or "Why is my outlet nil"...

Answer (score -1):

It is very common to use the navigationController in a tableView.Just put, in the method where you are handling the tap button event, something like this:

```
  let secondVC = YourViewControllerClass(customInitParam: param1, customInitParam2: param2,...)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondVC, animated: true)
```

Comment: He's asking how to present a view controller not push

Comment: To present a view controller just change 'pushViewController()' to `.present(ViewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool,  CompletionHandler: () -> ())`

Comment: Exactly. Hope it helps you ;)

Comment: Value of type 'CatPlaceTableViewCell' has no member 'navigationController'